# Wordpress order/sort problem

Tags: wordpress, sorting, post

**The Problem:**
I would like to sort my posts based on custom fields, when the user clicks on a link. I don't know if there is a parameter that can be passed via url to reorder posts.

**Comparison:**
I would like it to work similar to how you can sort songs in iTunes. The user simply clicks the "Artist" button and the songs are reorder alphabetically by artist's name.

**Example:**
The custom field could be the location where I was when I wrote the post. "Location = home" or "Location = office" etc. When the user click a links the page is reload with the posts reordered. Posts from home before ones from the office.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts('&meta_key=location&orderby=meta_value');`

This will sort by location, and exclude all posts that don't have a location field.